# Inno Setup установка дополнительного ПО

Tags: файлы, установка, inno-setup

Как в Inno Setup реализовать скрипт, чтобы кроме установки основной программы 
устанавливалось бы дополнительное ПО с информацией по этому ПО. 
Перед запуском инсталлятора нужна проверка на несколько условий.
1. Проверка на ГЕО, например RU и DE. 
2. Проверка реестра на определённые ключи. 
Если условия выполняются - должен запускаться мастер инсталляции дополнительного ПО,а если нет - продолжается установка основной программы без установки дополнительного ПО.

Answer (score 3):

В этом случае инсталлятор дополнительного ПО добавляется как дополнительный файл.

Например, нужно с программой поставить Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 Client Part.
Для этого добавляешь в инсталлятор файл установки dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe:

```
Source: "..\Libraries\dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; DestName: "dotnetfx.exe"; Flags: deleteafterinstall; Check: not IsFrameworkDetected(); AfterInstall: InstallFramework();
```

`Source` – атрибут, который содержит путь к файлу установки.

`DestDir` – атрибут, который содержит путь к директории, в которую будет скопирован файл установки.
`{tmp}` – макрос, который подставляет путь к папке с временными файлами.

`DestName` – атрибут, который содержит имя файла, которое будет назначено скопированному файлу установки.

`Flags`. Значение `deleteafterinstall` в атрибуте `Flags` говорит о том, что файл установки .NET должен быть удалён инсталлятором Inno Setup после установки .NET.

`Check`. Атрибут `Check` содержит код, который будет вызван перед тем, как Inno Setup решит копировать файл в директорию, указанной в `DestDir`. Если в атрибут `Check` передаётся значение True, то файл копируется, в противном случае операции с файлом пропускаются.
Пример функции `IsFrameworkDetected`:

```
function IsFrameworkDetected(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := IsDotNetDetected('v4\Client', 0);
end;
```

Реализацию функции `IsDotNetDetected` можно посмотреть [здесь](http://kynosarges.org/DotNetVersion.html).

`AfterInstall`. В атрибуте `AfterInstall` нужно указать код, который будет вызван сразу после копирования файла. В нашем случае это код, который запустит установку dotnetfx.exe.
Пример процедуры `InstallFramework`:

```
procedure InstallFramework();
var
  statusText: String;
  CurrentRebootRequired: boolean;
begin
  Log('InstallFramework');

  statusText := WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption;
  WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := ’Установка клиентского профиля Microsoft .NET Framework 4.’;
  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstMarquee;
  try
    InstallFrameworkExe(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\dotnetfx.exe'), CurrentRebootRequired)
    if CurrentRebootRequired then RebootRequired := true;
  except
    ShowExceptionMessage();
    ExitCode := 1;
  finally
    WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := statusText;
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstNormal;
  end;
end;
```

Использование `WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption` позволяет дополнительно информировать о том, что сейчас происходит.
Пример процедуры `InstallFrameworkExe`, которая запускает файл установки dotnetfx.exe:

```
const // Full list: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376931(v=vs.85).aspx
  ERROR_SUCCESS = 0;
  ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_INITIATED = 1641;
  ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED = 3010;

procedure InstallFrameworkExe(FilePath: string; var RebootRequired: boolean);
var
    ResultCode: integer;
begin
  Exec(FilePath, '/norestart', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, resultCode)
  Log('Framework is installed with code: ' + IntToStr(resultCode) + '.');
  if resultCode = ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED then
    RebootRequired := true
  else if ResultCode <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
    RaiseException(CustomMessage('FrameworkInstallationError'));
end;
```