# Прервать установку

Tags: inno-setup

Вот часть скрипта inno

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\Жека\Desktop\Goons Raid Her – New Version 0.2\directx.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; AfterInstall: Rundirectx
Source: "C:\Users\Жека\Desktop\Goons Raid Her – New Version 0.2\Goons Raid Her.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "C:\Users\Жека\Desktop\Goons Raid Her – New Version 0.2\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Code]
procedure Rundirectx;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\directx.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL,
    ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
  then
    MsgBox('directx failed to run!' + #13#10 +
      SysErrorMessage(ResultCode), mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

В данном скрипте перед распаковкой папки с игрой происходит установка directx. Как сделать так, что если пользователь отменил установку directx, то и отменялась бы операция распаковки папки с игрой? Выше в скрипте этого не происходит если прервать установку directx, то далее происходит распаковка папки с игрой.

Comment: [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/684684/11230) расписал. Проверяешь код возврата `ResultCode`, а там как хочешь, можешь RaiseException, можешь свою логику накручивать.

Comment: А можно пожалуйста точнее указать, что где поправить в скрипте, потому что я новичoк в inno только учусь.